# ng-submitted not added to form if form is invalid

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="controller/action"
      ng-controller="modelController as ctrl"
      method="post" class="form-horizontal"
      name="referencesForm">

    <input name="References[0].Position" ng-model="ctrl.model.References[0].Position" required type="text">
    <div class="clear-both">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> Save &amp; Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If the form is invalid and the form is submitted, `ng-submitted` is not added to the form's classes.

I want some css to only be applied when `ng-submitted` is on the form:

```
.ng-submitted .ng-invalid,
.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
    @include animated-border(#a94442);
}
```

Does the form have to be valid for ng-submitted to be added, if so, is there something else I can use to say that a submit has happened?

Comment: You don't want to submit an invalid form (typically), so it makes sense for `ng-submitted` to only be added when the form is actually submitted.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish when the form is either submitted and invalid, or submitted and valid?

Comment: I want to apply a css class to any invalid fields but only after a form submission attempt.  I don't want them to show invalid initially.  ng-touched won't work because that relies on the user actually having focus on the elements.

Comment: For that you need to add a flag and set the flag value only when you clicked submit button. Re write your validations to check flag also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show validations messages only after clicking on submit button you can make use of simple flags.

Add an `or` condition with `flag` while writing validation messages and when you click on `submit` button change `flag` value as `true`.

```
<form action="controller/action"
ng-controller="modelController as ctrl"
method="post" class="form-horizontal"
name="referencesForm">

<input name="References[0].Position" ng-model="ctrl.model.References[0].Position" required type="text">
<p ng-show="referencesForm.References[0].Position.$error||submitted "
<div class="clear-both">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitted=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> Save &amp; Continue</button>
</div>
```